# How to get a list of overdue tasks per person via the clickup API

Tags: javascript, n8n, clickup-api

**1. Straightforward approach**

If to check the dev tools in the Clickup app, there's a request

```
https://app.clickup.com/home/team/{team_id}/inbox
```

with payload

```
{userid: user_id, overdue_only: true, sort_by: "dueDate", sort_dir: -1, reminder_position: "top"}
```

That returns a list of overdue tasks+reminders IDs. It kinda answers my question, but it is undocumented, so I don't want really to wake up one day and see this endpoint is abandoned.

**2. Using the documentation**

The idea is to hardcode team id, get a list of all [spaces per team](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/GetSpaces/), then a list of [folders per space](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/GetFolders/), then a list of [lists per folders](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/GetLists/), then a [list of folderless lists per space](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/GetFolderlessLists/), then a list of [tasks with filter on assignees per list of lists](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/GetFolderlessLists/). Sounds like too much headache for a simple job.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As recommended by the Clickup support team, the best option (as of current version) is to use [filtered tasks](https://clickup.com/api/clickupreference/operation/GetFilteredTeamTasks/):

[https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/team/%team_id%/task?assignees[]=%assignee_id%&due_date_lt=%unix_time_with_millisecinds%](https://api.clickup.com/api/v2/team/%team_id%/task?assignees%5B%5D=%assignee_id%&due_date_lt=%unix_time_with_millisecinds%)